# Updating tkinter label

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to update a label, but the code I have written creates a new label each time. I am relatively new to tkinter so I couldn't understand how to apply other answers to my code.

```
from tkinter import *
import random

class Window(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master) 
        self.master=master 
        self.init_window()

    def init_window(self): 
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        testButton=Button(self, text="Press", command=calc)
        testButton.pack()
        l1=Label(text="")

    def testbutton(ans): #creates a new instance of l1 each time, I want to update existing l1
        var=StringVar()
        l1=Label(textvariable=var) #l1.configure() gives error l1 not defined
        var.set(ans)
        l1.pack()

def calc():
    list1=["a","b","c"]
    index=random.randint(0,2)
    answer=list1[index]
    Window.testbutton(answer)

root=Tk()
root.geometry("400x300")
app=Window(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Each time the button is pressed, a new label is created, instead of updating the text on the existing label. 
This is a simplified version of my actual project, but highlights the issue with labels. 
I've tried to use `l1.configure(...)` inside the testbutton function but then it runs an error that l1 isn't defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid creating a new `Label` each time, you need to make one and save it as an attribute of the `Window` instance. To make it accessible to the `calc()` function, you'll also need to pass the `Window` instance to it as an argument (to avoid using global variables). A common why to do that with `tkinter` is by using a `lamba` function as the `Button`'s `command=` argument and making `self` the default value for its argument as shown below.

```
from tkinter import *
import random

class Window(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.init_window()

    def init_window(self):
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        testButton = Button(self, text="Press",
                            command=lambda win=self: calc(win))
        testButton.pack()
        self.l1 = Label(text="")
        self.l1.pack()

    def testbutton(self, ans):
        self.l1.configure(text=ans)

def calc(window):  # note window argument added
    list1 = ["a","b","c"]
    index = random.randint(0,2)
    answer = list1[index]
    window.testbutton(answer)

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x300")
app = Window(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you, this solves my problem. Why does the l1 label in init_window need the self.l1...?

Comment: Becky: The `self.l1 = Label(text="")` is how the `Label` widget that's created is attached to the `Window` instance for later reference. In Python you can create new instance attributes at any time by assigning a value to the name you want to use: i.e.`self.attribute_name = ...`. You can also delete them with `del self.attribute_name`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use class methods and attributes.
Use a `StringVar` to change label text:

```
class Window(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.init_window()

    def init_window(self):
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        testButton = Button(self, text="Press", command=self.calc)
        testButton.pack()
        self.ltext = StringVar()
        l1 = Label(textvariable=self.ltext)
        l1.pack()

    def testbutton(self, ans):
        self.ltext.set(ans)

    def calc(self):
        list1 = ["a", "b", "c"]
        index = random.randint(0, 2)
        answer = list1[index]
        self.testbutton(answer)

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x300")
app = Window(root)
root.mainloop()
```